# Are these SQL queries equivalent?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm quite new to SQL. The first query is "correct" but I want to rewrite it so that it returns nothing instead of "Ok". Query #2 is my try. According to me, it is correct because the `JOIN` condition separates all rows where the two dates are different. But I'm not sure at this and as I said I'm kind a new to this.. The problem is that I have no test-data right to cross verify. Could you please help?

## 1

```
DECLARE @date1 datetime, 
                     @date2 datetime
SELECT  @date1 = Max(date) FROM table1
WHERE 1 = 1
        AND id = 1
        AND id2 = 11

SELECT  @date2 = Max(date) FROM table2
WHERE 1 = 1
        AND id = 2
        AND id2 = 11

SELECT 
        CASE 
                     WHEN COALESCE(@date1,0) = @date2 
                                 THEN 'Ok'
                     WHEN  CONVERT(TIME,GETDATE()) < '19:00:00' 
                                 THEN  'Ok'
                                 ELSE  'Not Ok'
        END AS Warning
```

## 2:

```
DECLARE  @date1 datetime
    ,@date2 datetime
    ,@id int = 1

SELECT  @date1 = COALESCE(MAX(date),0) FROM table1
WHERE 1 = 1
AND id = @id
AND id3 = 11
SELECT  @date2= MAX(date) FROM table1
WHERE 1 = 1
AND id = @id
AND id2 = 11


SELECT 
    'Warning' = CASE WHEN  CONVERT(TIME,GETDATE()) > '19:00:00' 
                     THEN  'not ok'
                END
FROM dbo.table1 AS a
INNER JOIN dbo.table AS a2 ON 1 = 1
AND @date1 != @date2
WHERE 1 = 1
AND a.nBranchId = @id
AND a.nInstrId = 11
```

Comment: Why all these `WHERE 1 = 1`. And why on earth join on `1=1`?!? Parsing and understanding such a query using only brainpower is though, it's better to run the two queries and compare the results. Select into a temporary table (`SELECT * INTO #tmp1 FROM ...`) and make queries that compare the two tables.

Comment: Well, in my head I think: Do they return the same values? Then they are equivalent...

Comment: @Tobb It's just something we do on my company to make it easier to test (when comment out rows and so on...)

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar That's the problem. I have tried to read the logic and in my head I see no difference. But I have no data to try this on...

Comment: There could be different results for `NULL` values due to `COALESCE` in the second query.

Comment: @VDohnal What do you mean?

Comment: If `MAX(tmDate) IS NULL` then COALESCE(MAX(tmDate),0) returns 0, nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not nearly equivalent. In both versions, the `@date1` variable will be NULL if there are no rows satisfying the conditions of the  query used to initialise its value.

If that's the case, the last select from version 1 will return a single row with value being either "Ok" or "Forwardpoints missing in XP_ResultsOutRightForwards", depending on the current time.

The version 2, however, will not return any rows whatsoever because you used this variable in the condition of an `inner join`. The inequality does not work with NULL values, so you will receive an empty set.

Comment: So If I use ISNULL instead of COALESCE that would solve the problem with NULL?

Comment: @krillezzz, In this case, `isnull()` and `coalesce()` are identical. I would rather change the assignment expression for this variable, like in the first query: `SELECT  @MaxDateXPR = isnull(MAX(tmDate), 0) FROM XP_Results ...` But you will still have 0 rows if those 2 variables are different.